# Core data crash on iOS 5.1

Tags: core-data, ios5, crash

I have a really strange core data issue.

My entity contains only string attributes (exactly 29). When I want to add new string attribute to core data entity I get core data crash while saving context (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). This happens only on iOS 5.1, not on 6 or 7. To be clear, it's not migration issue, I'm doing a fresh install after each change...

Even more strange is when I add a boolean property, I'm able to add more strings into this entity without application crash.

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Do you use multiple managed object contexts?

Comment: Try an exception breakpoint and/or activate the zombies and profile with Instruments.

Comment: I'm using single context, exception breakpoint is catched on save, but I can't step over it... Zombies didn't provide any info. It just crashes on first save when I created new record for that entity